# How to track 5-Star rating

Tags: html, analytics, rating, event-tracking

I have the following simple 5 star rating code, is there an easy way to track which star value the user clicks? the goal is to have a document or database or whatever that tells me "there was a user here yesterday that clicked on 4 stars"

> ```
> <div class="rate">
> <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
> <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
> <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
> <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
> <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
> <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
> <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
> <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
> <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
> <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
> </div>
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you searching for an code solution? In your own DB? With todays analytics tools you can simple use an click event on `.rate input`.

Comment: I guess you need a click event and record the value. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218516/creating-simple-star-rating-using-click-event-javascript

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".rate input" ).click(function() {
        console.log("User chose: " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.